# I'm trying to create protected routes using latest react-router-dom v6.11 through createBrowserRouter. But it's not working. Some help please

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

```
import "./App.css";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import ConfessionsPage from "./pages/ConfessionsPage";
import HelpPage from "./pages/HelpPage";
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { VentifyContext } from "./context/VentifyContextProvider";

function App() {
  const publicRoutes = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <HomePage />,
    },
    {
      path: "/help",
      element: <HelpPage />,
    },
  ];

  const protectedRoutes = [
    ...publicRoutes,
    {
      path: "/confessions",
      element: <ConfessionsPage />,
    },
  ];

  const { userIsLoggedIn } = useContext(VentifyContext);

  const publicRouter = createBrowserRouter(publicRoutes);
  const protectedRouter = createBrowserRouter(protectedRoutes);

  const [router, setRouter] = useState(publicRouter);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRouter(userIsLoggedIn ? protectedRouter : publicRouter);
  }, [userIsLoggedIn]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

it's not able to find protected routes when user logged in and `userIsloggedIn` value changes to `true`. ii'm using useEffect hook so that it render the logic again but still protected routes are not accessible.

Comment: Don't protect routes by conditionally rendering them, they typically won't be mounted and rendered when you are trying to navigate to them upon auth changes. Unconditionally render them and conditionally redirect off them when auth conditions are not met.